# NSUserDefaults objectForKey keeps returning nil, even when key exists

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save data in NSUserDefaults. The very first time this code (and app) loops, it should go through the if-statement. Because no data was saved in NSUserdefaults was saved yet with the names: BoughtItem0, BoughtItem1, BoughtItem2, BoughtItem3.

But somehow after looping the code for the first time, and so starting my app for the second time it keeps going through the if-statement. What's wrong in my code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [shopPrices count]; i++)
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BoughtItem%d"] == nil)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"NONO" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BoughtItem%d", i]];
        NSLog(@"BoughtItem%d", i);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No new bought item keys made");
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
BoughtItem0
BoughtItem1
BoughtItem2
BoughtItem3
```

Comment: Try using `setObject:forKey`. If that doesn't work, call `synchronize` after you set all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have used a format string in your call to `objectForKey` but you have omitted the call to `stringWithFormat`. I think what you meant was -

```
for (int i = 0; i < [shopPrices count]; i++)
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BoughtItem%d",i]] == nil)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"NONO" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BoughtItem%d", i]];
        NSLog(@"BoughtItem%d", i);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No new bought item keys made");
    }
}
```

You had it in the setValue, just not in your `if`, so you were checking for the existence of the key "BoughtItem%d", but you were setting "BoughtItem0"...

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer to my question. Can't believe I didn't see that.